# When using semver when to upgrade/bump to 1.0.0 (stable)

Tags: semantic-versioning

The Semantic Versioning Specification ([SemVer](http://semver.org/)) defines:

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

So starting with `1.0.0` is considered stable.

When starting a project normally version `0.1.0` is used and gradually increased, there is a point where the project can have something like `0.20.3` for months/years and it is "stable".

Therefore would like to know what could be considered good practices to follow besides the criteria, arguments before bumping a project to server `1.0.0`.

How you are dealing with this?

If there are not issues/code activity in 3 months the version is dumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development team decides when they have version 1.0.0.  It is possible for a project to remain in experimental/prototype mode for very long periods of time.  The only thing that matters here is whether the interface and implementation can be considered complete or not.  What are your goals?  Do you have all the planned v1 features in place?  Do you have doubts w.r.t. implementation conformance to the documented interface?

Some teams don't have workflows that map onto the full [semver spec](https://semver.org), but they use packaging/release tooling that requires a semver version string. In order to be legal, they never release version 1.0.0, so any version bumps literally don't have full SemVer semantics.  See [#4 in the spec](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4).

When I see SomeLib.0.20.3.pkg I assume it is not stable. A breaking change can occur on the very next minor field bump, whether or not there have ever been any such changes in the past.  SemVer is a contract that allows the SomeLib developers to break things without notice in this particular case.

There is nothing in the spec that precludes a team from issuing a 1.0.0 and then returning to a long sequence of 0.x.x releases if they so desire to operate that way.  This is similar to, but not exactly the same as using prerelease tags. When you issue 1.0.1-prerelease you are at least implying intent to release a work derived from 1.0.0 that is a bug-fix, but the prerelease tag is warning label that you are not yet certain of the safety of the changes you made.  Following on from 1.0.0 to a sequence of 0.x.x releases says you might not even be deriving from 1.0.0 anymore. Basically, all bets are off again.

If you require any further elucidation on this matter, please ask, I am happy to try to answer any questions regarding SemVer.